# Haskell: Improving my tail-recursive fibonacci implementation

Tags: haskell, fibonacci, tail-recursion

I have come up with the following tail-recursive fibonacci generator that works:

```
let {
  fibo :: Integral x => [x]->x->x->x->[x]
  fibo l x y 0 = l
  fibo l x y n = fibo (l ++ [y+x] ++ [y+x+y]) (x+y) (y+x+y) (n-1)
}
```

Pardon me for the whole implementation put in one line because i am using the GHCi and haven't quite learnt how to put this in a file and run (i am yet to reach there). What i want to know is how this call:

```
fibo [0, 1] 0 1 5
```

can be improved. I do not want to pass the initial list with 0 and 1 and then pass 0 and 1 again with the limit. I believe that the implementation can be changed. What changes can be done?

Comment: You can just write it in a file line by line like you would in the interpreter (no need to wrap everything up in a let block either), and then load the file in the interpreter (in GHCi with :l filename)

Comment: Your code is tail-recursive, but nevertheless very inefficient, as `(++)` is linear in its first argument. But I guess that this is not part of the question.

Comment: Tail recursion in Haskell does not entail constant stack usage like it does in strict languages, and conversely non-tail recursion doesn't entail linear stack usage either, so I question the value of your exercise.  Frankly, I'd go with the classic `fibs = 0 : 1 : zipWith (+) fibs (tail fibs)` or one of its variants with `scanl` or `unfoldr`.  See [this HaskellWiki page](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/The_Fibonacci_sequence) for a bunch of implementations.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your algorithm is tail-recursive, but it looks like it has other drawbacks, namely 1) you are building the result list by appending to the end of it, and 2) it's not lazy.

For 1), note that when you append two lists `a ++ b`, you essentially have to reallocate `a`. In your case `a` is the growing list of fibonacci numbers and `b` are the next two terms. So each iteration reallocates the fibonacci numbers that have already been computed and adds on two more elements which will result in quadratic running time. It would be more efficient to prepend `b` to the front of `a`. You'll be producing the fibonacci numbers in reverse, but the running time will be linear. You can then `reverse` the list at the end if you want the sequence in ascending order.

Note that building the list in reverse order allows you to easily get at the last two terms of the sequence by using Code-Guru's pattern-matching idea.

For 2), note that you can't get the first element of the list until the entire computation has completed. Compare with the following lazy generation of the sequence:

```
fibs = 0 : (go 0 1)
  where go a b = b : go b (a+b)
```

Even though it looks like the recursion never stops, `fibs` is only evaluated for as much as is needed. For example, `fibs !! 3` only calls `go` a couple of times.

Comment: ...which means i can control recursion from outside the function in Haskell?

Comment: yes - that's one way to look at it - you don't have to decide ahead of time how many terms to compute

Answer (score 4):

I'm not going to go to the algorithm itself, but here's some advice on how to structure your recursive functions.

First, here's how you would format your code in a separate file

```
fibo :: Integral x => [x]->x->x->x->[x]
fibo l x y 0 = l
fibo l x y n = fibo (l ++ [y+x] ++ [y+x+y]) (x+y) (y+x+y) (n-1)
```

If you save this as fibo.hs, then you can start GHCi with

```
ghci fibo.hs
```

to load the file at start. You can also load the file after starting GHCi with the command

```
:l fibo.hs
```

(assumming you start GHCi in the same directory where you saved fibo.hs)

Another nice feature is that now when you edit the file, you can reload all your changes by simply entering

```
:r
```

in the GHCi prompt.

Now, to get rid of the extra parameters, the usual pattern in Haskell is to refactor the recursive part to its own helper function and have the main function as an entry point that only takes the necessary parameters. For example,

```
fibo :: Integral x => x -> [x]
fibo n = fiboHelper [0,1] 0 1 n

fiboHelper :: Integral x => [x]->x->x->x->[x]
fiboHelper l x y 0 = l
fiboHelper l x y n = fiboHelper (l ++ [y+x] ++ [y+x+y]) (x+y) (y+x+y) (n-1)
```

Now you can call `fibo` simply with

```
> fibo 3
[0,1,1,2,3,5,8,13]
```

Also, a helper function like this that is not useful by itself is usually hidden inside the main function as an inner function using `let` or `where`.

```
fibo :: Integral x => x -> [x]
fibo n = fiboHelper [0,1] 0 1 n where
    fiboHelper l x y 0 = l
    fiboHelper l x y n = fiboHelper (l ++ [y+x] ++ [y+x+y]) (x+y) (y+x+y) (n-1)
```

An inner function like this is usually given a shorter name, because the context makes its purpose clear, so we could change the name to e.g. `fibo'`.

`go` is another commonly used name for a recursive helper function.

Answer (score 3):

Just for the record: The "usual" definition for a list of Fibonacci numbers is:

```
fibo = 0 : scanl (+) 1 fibo
```

Comment: Or (a little bit less arcane) `fibo = 0 : 1 : zipWith (+) fibo (tail fibo)`